# In R, use an if statement for an object when creating a list

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

How can I use an if-statement for an object when creating a list (for creating an interaction variable using mutate in dplyr)?

Please see the example data below.

```
# Example data
set.seed(1)
x <- sample(1:2, 10, replace = T)
y <- sample(1:2, 10, replace = T)
z <- sample(1:2, 10, replace = T)
df <- data.frame(x, y, z)

condition <- list()
# Testing 1 versus NULL for the if statement below
condition$x <- 1
condition$x <- NULL

df %>% 
  # This condition works: 
  { if(!is.null(condition$x[1])) filter(., x %in% condition$x) else . } %>%
  mutate(condition = interaction(
    list(
      # This if statement does not work
     {if(!is.null(condition$x[1])) x}, 
      y, 
      z
    )
  ))
```

In words, I want to have one if-statement for whether to use a variable for `filter` or not (which works). Then I want the same if statement for whether that variable should be included or not when creating an interaction variable for the included variables.

Comment: Can you explain in words what your code does, or should do?

Comment: I have tried to describe it in the end of the post now :) Thank you for the help.

Comment: First you create a list member with `condition$x <- 1` then you remove that member with `condition$x <- NULL`. See what is `condition` after this last statement.

Comment: I think OP intended these lines to be run selectively for testing. @RuiBarradas

Does this help you? [Applying interaction to user specified columns…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69588506/applying-interaction-to-user-specified-column-from-within-a-tidyverse-pipe)

Comment: @uke Thanks, it does help. I hadn't realized that the code depends on `condition`.

Comment: @John Use `setdiff` to exclude `x` in the `else`, see [updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75976013/6574038), should scale well now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following -

```
library(dplyr)

cond_var <- condition$x[1]
is_valid <- !is.null(cond_var)

df %>% 
  filter({
    if(is_valid)
      x %in% condition$x
    else TRUE #TRUE keeps all the rows
  }) %>%
  mutate(condition = if(is_valid) interaction(x, y, z) else interaction(y, z))
```

Comment: thanks, this produces the results I want. But it does not scale very well for more combintations of variables in the interactions... know of any better solution?

Comment: Well, it is not clear to me what you mean by "more combinations" but here is one tip that may help. You can pass dynamic column values to `interaction` function using `do.call`. Eg - `cols <- c('mpg', 'disp'); do.call(interaction, mtcars[cols])` is same as doing `interaction(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$disp)`. In your case you need to identify what this `cols` is going to be.

Answer (score 2):

Base R

```
cond <- list(x=1)
# cond <- list(x=NULL)

if (!is.null(cond$x)) {
  sst <- as.list(subset(df, x %in% cond$x))
  transform(sst, condition=do.call(interaction, sst))
} else {
  transform(df, condition=do.call(interaction, df[setdiff(names(df), 'x')]))
}
#   x y z condition
# 1 1 1 1     1.1.1
# 3 1 1 1     1.1.1
# 4 1 1 1     1.1.1
# 6 1 2 1     1.2.1
# 7 1 2 2     1.2.2
# 8 1 2 1     1.2.1
```

dplyr

```
library(dplyr)

cond <- list(x=1)
# cond <- list(x=NULL)

df %>% 
  {
    if (!is.null(cond$x)) {
      filter(., x %in% cond$x) %>% 
        mutate(condition=do.call(interaction, .))
    } else {
      mutate(df, condition=do.call(interaction, df[setdiff(names(df), 'x')]))
    }
  }
#   x y z condition
# 1 1 1 1     1.1.1
# 2 1 1 1     1.1.1
# 3 1 1 1     1.1.1
# 4 1 2 1     1.2.1
# 5 1 2 2     1.2.2
# 6 1 2 1     1.2.1
```

---

*Data:*

```
 df <- structure(list(x = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), 
    y = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), z = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```